# Project Euler 9 - help understanding solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, project-euler

I've been trying to understand the proof for a solution to the [Euler 9 problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=9). I'm on [this site](http://www.mathblog.dk/pythagorean-triplets/) under the heading "Solving the problem". I've understood the parts that came before it (excluding the "proof" )

[IMO, reading the project euler problem is not necessary to understand what's happening below]

[image]

I'm specifically wondering how the author concluded that since $m|(s/2)\implies m<\sqrt{s/2}$. I mean, even $12$ divides $48$ but $12>\sqrt(48)\approx 7$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: $s=2m(m+n)d \implies s/2=m(m+n)d>m^2$

Comment: @Joffan Ok, i get this, and I suppose this has nothing to do whether $m|(s/2)$. Am I correct?

Comment: It's implied by the same equation, since $m$ is a simple factor

Comment: @Joffan No, I meant that in case had the equation been $s/2=(m+1)(m+n)d$, the result that $m<\sqrt{s/2}$ would be unaffected, even though now $m$ does not divide $s/2$.

Comment: @Joffan that's what I needed "Yes, they are two outcomes of the given equation, not derived from each other (in either direction" Please post an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Done. I was also pondering the implications for $n$, but we can't say anything much about that; certainly we don't have $n\mid s$, since eg. $4\mid 28$ and $(4+3) \mid 28$ but $3\nmid 28$.

Comment: @Joffan Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s=2m(m+n)d \implies s/2=m(m+n)d>m^2$ so $\color{blue}{m<\sqrt {s/2}}$

Also, $s/2=m(m+n)d \implies \color{blue}{m \mid s/2}$

So those are two outcomes of the given equation, not derived from each other (in either direction).